# socket.io troubles - 404 (Not Found)

Tags: sockets, io, server

Despite following the exact instructions of this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pNKNYLv2BpQ and changing details where necessary (e.g. I am using localhost:8888 as oppose to 3000), I am always getting error messages, no matter what I try. It is becoming extremely frustrating as I can't, for the life of me, figure out where I am going wrong.

I am currently getting the error message `GET http://localhost:8888/socket.io/1/?t=1462670368869 404 (Not Found)`after a massive struggle of continuously getting an error where it couldn't locate the 'socket.io.js' file. Can anyone shed some light on this devastatingly cryptic topic?

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Chat with socket.io and node.js</title>
    <style>
        #chat{
            height:500px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="chat"></div>
    <form id="send-message">
        <input size="35" id="message"></input>
        <input type="submit"></input>
    </form>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script src="socket.io.js"></script>


    <script>
        jQuery(function($){
            var socket = io.connect();
            var $messageForm = $('#send-message');
            var $messageBox = $('#message');
            var $chat = $('#chat');

            $messageForm.submit(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                socket.emit('send message', $messageBox.val());
                $messageBox.val('');
            });

            socket.on('new message', function(data){
                $chat.append(data + "<br/>");
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript:

```
var express = require('express');
    app = express();
    server = require('http').createServer(app);
    io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

server.listen(8888);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendfile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){
    socket.on('send message', function(data){
        io.sockets.emit('new message', data);
    });
});
```

JSON:

```
{
  "name": "chat",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": "true",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.10.2",
    "socket.io": "^0.9.16"
  }
}
```